# How to suspend process on a Heroku cedar stack

Tags: process, heroku, cedar

I have a small app on Heroku's cedar stack that uses two processes. One runs the Sinatra server and the other collects tweets and inserts them into a database. This project is still in development and while Heroku offers one process for free, the second process costs money.

I'd like to keep the Sinatra server running but suspend the tweet collector process from time to time. If you run `heroku stop tweet_collector.1` it will temporarily stop the process but then it appears the `Procfile` restarts it. I haven't found a way to comment out processes in the `Procfile` so I've simply deleted the process from the file and pushed it.

Can you override the `Procfile` from commandline and stop a process? If not, how can you comment out a process in the `Procfile` so it's not read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can scale any of your Procfile entries to zero using heroku scale:

```
heroku scale web=0
```

More information here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: nice, this allows the Procfile to not be messed with